# How to convert "Number" into number In karate

Tags: api, cucumber, karate

How to convert this "2203" to 2203
Tried with some given examples, no Luck
Jobid="2203"

```
* def Jobid = response  # Jobid="2203"
    * def intJobid = function(x){ x.Jobid = ~~x.Jobid; return x }
    * def results = karate.map(intJobid, Jobid)
    * match results == #number
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `parseInt()` to convert string to number. An alternative is to just multiply the string with 1. e.g.

```
* def foo = '10'
* string json = { bar: '#(1 * foo)' }
* match json == '{"bar":10.0}'

* string json = { bar: '#(parseInt(foo))' }
* match json == '{"bar":10.0}'
```

Source: https://intuit.github.io/karate/#floats-and-integers

Comment: This not working when the response is passed  * string json = { Activejob: '#(1 * response)' } or even stored response in def and while i print json "Activejob": NaN this value is displayed which is not correct is just want to remove double quotes from number and when value is hardcoded Like * def response = "10"  then its working fine

Comment: this * string is insane ! lol
but working